# Too many errors after updating to Cocoapods 1.0

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Good afternoon,

After updating to the latest version of Cocoapods (1.0) my iOS application shows a lot of errors. I'm not sure why is this happening because during the update everything was correct, but when I "Run" my app, it shows the following errors:

[image: 28 issues]

And that's my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'myApp' do

pod 'HanekeSwift', '~> 0.10'

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.3'

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'

pod 'Batch', '~> 1.5'

end

target 'myAppTests' do

end

target 'myAppUITests' do

end
```

What can I do in order to solve those problems?

Much appreciated,

Regards.

Comment: You could stop using CocoaPods and use Carthage instead. Made the change a few months ago and never looked back. https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage (No affiliation here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran `pod install` and its still not working.
Try `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install`. It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem, I have deleted the old Podfile and create a new one. And now that's how it looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'myApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myApp
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
  pod 'HanekeSwift', '~> 0.10'
  pod 'Batch', '~> 1.5'

  target 'myAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'myAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```